# Need CKEditor to encode special characters

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I would like CKEditor to encode all special characters. Currently it only html escapes >, <, and & I believe.

I need the current **html markup** of this

`Let's take a "ride!"`

to become *something* like this

`Let&rsquo;s take a &ldquo;ride!&rdquo;`

In this situation, the `Let's take a "ride!"` is still what would display to the user, but the html should reflect the encoding so my styling is properly applied.

I am seeing that Drupal 7 had a config.js file that could be modified to accommodate this; however, Drupal 8 does not have this by default and does not seem to recognize it when one is created.

Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

EDIT: our content authors are using the Basic HTML editor permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to alter your twig template to include [escape](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html). There are plenty of examples in that guide.

Comment: I modified the original question to hopefully be more clear. The end-user should still see the first example, but I need the html markup (and what is stored in the database) to reflect the second example so my styling can be properly applied.